# How to use ImagePyramids in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, image-pyramids

I want a cheaper solution than ESRI ArcGIS server for my online web GIS applications.
I want to:

- display multiple SHP files and an aerial image,
- retrieve the SHP attributes,
- all in a web page inside my PHP applications.

I tried Geoserver, and got stuck in tiling the aerial images, plus the performance is not that good.
When I used ImagePyramid for example, I had the universal problem

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them:
> This plugin accepts only File, URL and String pointing to a file

I tried to google it, found a lot of other users faced the same problem, no straight online tutorial describes the required steps or how to troubleshoot the mistakes.

Any help or suggestion for alternatives?

Comment: Are you looking for a desktop GIS product or a web-GIS product suite?

Comment: I've updated the question - i need a web GIS server .

Comment: What are the typical GIS tasks you want to accomplish besides tiling aerial images?  One of the most recommended "free" alternatives seems to be QGIS. Personally, I am an ArcGIS user and although I have tried some alternatives none proved a suitable replacements but It may be because cartography and map presentation is a major component of what I do. None of the alternative products offered the same level of sophistication.  If you are looking for spatial data management, geoprocessing, etc. there might be good alternatives but you might need to provide us with more info.

Comment: I see you've updated your question. Disregard the above comment.

Comment: @Jakub , i want to display multiple SHP files , an aerial image , retrieving the SHP attributes , all in a web page inside my php applications .

Comment: Geoserver and GeoWebCache http://smathermather.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/geoserver-and-efficient-delivery-of-raster-data-image-pyramid-layer/ works well

Comment: ImageMosaic Plugin and ImagePyramid Plugin are totally complicated , i've been struggling with them two weeks ago .

Comment: What are you stuck with? - Either pay for bloated software or use 'free' OpenSource software - there is no out of the box solution - give us more info on what you had and now need and it will be easier to help you find a way.

Comment: When i used ImagePyramid for example , I had the Universal problem `Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: This plugin accepts only File, URL and String pointing to a file` , tried to google it , found a lot of other users faced the same problem , no straight online tutorial describes the required steps or how to troubleshoot the mistakes .

Comment: [Mapserver](http://www.mapserver.org) can use [PHP](http://www.mapserver.org/mapscript/php/index.html).  For something less DIY, the [pmapper](http://www.pmapper.net/index.shtml) framework uses Mapserver and PHP/MapScript.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) is dead-on for your requirements, and I think you'll be hard-pressed to find something that outperforms it when configured properly.  The php MapScript bindings should get you going quite nicely.

Comment: Do you have a link for php MapScript bindings?

Comment: http://www.maptools.org/php_mapscript/

Answer (score 0):

you can use image pyramid for raster files(geotiff) not vector files(shp).geoserver is good for that.for using geoserver your dedicated or vps server minimum ram must be 4g.ram 6g is good and 8g is best.
for list of layers you can use postgis for that.
if you don't like geoserver you can add them to postgis server and publish with openlayers (javascript).